# How to set up a titan1.0 + hbase0.98 cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, cluster-computing, titan

I have read the Titan Documentation 1.0, but I am still confused about how set up a cluster environment. 
1)For example, I already has hbase installed in 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, then should I deploy titan on all the three servers or any of them? 
2)After reading the Titan Documentation, I still don't know how to use the java api or rest api to communicate with the titan server?
3)Since Titan 1.0 introduces the interface with Spark, the I simply don't know how... 
Looking forward to the answers or other materials that I should read through, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1)For example, I already has hbase installed in 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, then should I deploy titan on all the three servers or any of them?

That is an architectural decision you need to make. There are [different ways](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/hbase.html) of deploying Titan and you need to choose the one that is right for you.

> 2)After reading the Titan Documentation, I still don't know how to use the java api or rest api to communicate with the titan server?

Titan packages Gremlin Server with the default distribution and refers to it as Titan Server. You can therefore just look at the documentation for Gremlin Server to determine how to communicate with via [REST](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#_connecting_via_rest) or [gremlin-driver](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#_connecting_via_java).

> 3)Since Titan 1.0 introduces the interface with Spark, the I simply don't know how

I don't know what you are asking here. All I can say is that Titan gets much of its functionality from TinkerPop and the Spark implementation is no different. It is TinkerPop that provides the API that you would use to interact with Spark, so read the [TinkerPop documentation on that topic](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#sparkgraphcomputer).